# JFace TreeViewer doesn't update when element is added to model

Tags: java, java-8, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I know this has a few answers, but none of them are working for me. Also the questions are a bit different because I'm using my own model implementation.

This code shows what should happen on button click.

Here the content is set to the tree viewer:

```
root = new TreeRootModel(solverEntries, null, configParser.getConfFile());
root.addInstances(instances);
viewer.setInput(new TreeRootModel[] { root });
column.pack(); // important to see TreeViewer at start
viewer.expandAll();
```

The TreeRootModel class is just a storage class under which an array is stored, with getter and setter. Not worth showing here.

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(newMainComposite, SWT.FLAT | SWT.WRAP | SWT.RIGHT);
ToolItem addItem = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
addItem.setText("Add");
addItem.setImage(addIcon);

addItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        InstanceModel newInstance = new InstanceModel("new Instance", null);
        instances.add(newInstance);
        // none of these three calls has an effect
        viewer.refresh();
        tree.update();
        column.pack();
    }
});
```

So the content of the TreeViewer is root, and root contains the List "instances". These objects will be displayed in the TreeViewer. Upon clicking the add button, an object is added to the List instances. I want to see that immediately in the TreeViewer.

The ContentProvider's inputChanged method is empty.

```
public class GoalInstanceContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider, IResourceChangeListener {

    TreeRootModel root;
    ArrayList<InstanceModel> instances = new ArrayList<>();
    private TreeViewer viewer;
    private TreeRootModel[] input;

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        if (inputElement instanceof TreeRootModel) {
            root = (TreeRootModel) inputElement;
            return root.getInstances().toArray();
        } else if (inputElement instanceof ArrayList) {
            instances = (ArrayList<InstanceModel>) inputElement;
            return instances.toArray();
        }
        return ArrayContentProvider.getInstance().getElements(inputElement);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is `instances` in the `addSelectionListener`? How is it related to `root.getInstances()` in the content provider. Your code must update the data that the content provider returns in `getElements` to make `refresh` work.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you mean to say when you do `root.addInstances(instances);` it should trigger `addSelectionListener`, is it correct ?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mentioned. But my question was for OP @Sadik

Comment: @greg-449 your comment helped me solve this issue. I set root.addInstances(instances) before, and totally forgot that updating instances will not update root::instances. If you write that as short answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Stop putting `root` inside of an array when setting the input. Use it directly.

Comment: I want to see that root instance in the tree viewer.